# Given a class function, is the preimage of a set a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the preimage of a set under a class function again a set?

Comment: Class function, not "functional".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the class function $F(x)=\varnothing$ for all $x\in V$, is such an easy example.